# How to design nav bar with dynamic content

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on the design of a webpage but i'm having difficulties achieving my visual mockup:

[Webpage design mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl8a7.png)

Right now, I'm not worried about section 1. What i want is to design the section 2. My website uses Angular 5 and Bootstrap 3, together with ngx-bootstrap library to add Bootstrap components to Angular. So far I have the following code:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- Schedule / Budget Navbar-->
    <tabset type="pills">
      <tab heading="Schedule"></tab>
      <tab heading="Budget"></tab>
    </tabset>
</div>  
<div class="row"> <!-- Schedule / Budget Content -->
  <!-- <app-schedule/> OR <app-budget> -->
</div>
```

Style:

```
.nav-pills > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
     zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
}

.nav-pills {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-pills > li > a{
    color: black!important; 
}

.nav-pills > li > a.active{
    background-color: #424242!important;
    color: white!important; 
}
```

[How it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMlij.png)

But I want the buttons to be designed just like in the mockup. I'd also like for the section 2 after the nav bar to present the content depending on whether the budget or the schedule is selected. I was considering adding one component for each of those two functionalities and dynamically changing between the elements `<app-budget/>` and `<app-schedule/>`, and the components would attach to the respective one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use routing. Assuming you have both the components: schedule and budget, in your app.component write:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- Schedule / Budget Navbar-->
    <tabset type="pills">
      <a routerLink="/schedule"><tab heading="Schedule"></tab></a>
      <a routerLink="/budget"><tab heading="Budget"></tab></a>
    </tabset>
</div>  
<div class="row"> <!-- Schedule / Budget Content -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Now in your app.module.ts import RouterModule and add:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'schedule', component: ScheduleComponent },
            { path: 'budget', component: BudgetComponent },
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
        ])
```

in the imports array.

For styling the buttons when one component is selected, take a look at RouterLinkActive.
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Official docs: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5